# Best Project Template to use for Classic Web Service

Tags: c#, .net

I'm going to create a new PayPal project.  Should I just create a regular Class Library project then add the reference to the WSDL?  We are not using WCF.  I just want to know what the best project type / template I should use if I'm going to share this project with lets say another WAP web project.  I simply want to create wrappers for some of the WSDL that we'll be using in part of the PayPal API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes a class library project seems the right thing to use if you're wrapping the code that consumes a web service.

Unless it's going to be tiny (say, just one class) in which case you might want to include it in an existing common project that is already used by both of your consuming projects, just to keep everything a little simpler.